# Two local networks, but Windows Web Server 2008 chooses wrong connection for accessing the internet

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking

We have some servers running Windows Web Server 2008.
They have two network cards. One with a private IP of the 172.X address space and one with the 10.X address space. The one with the 10.X address space is deactivated.

Both have their own switch and both are connected to a pfesense server.

The network with the 172.X addresses uses 1:1 NAT from pfsense to connect it with the public static IP. So for every private 172.X address we have public IP addresses. Our servers can connect to the Internet and users can connect to the servers. Everything works fine.

But as soon as we activate the second NIC with the 10.X address space, Windows Web Server 2008 isn't able to connect to the Internet anymore.

So I think it is a routing issue.
**How can I tell Windows Web Server 2008 to use the 172.X NIC to connect to the Internet?**

EDIT:

The following command will work till the dhcp lease of the 10.X NIC gets refreshed or the card gets deactivated and reactivated. Then I need to enter the command again:

```
route -p delete 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 10.0.1.1
```

EDIT 2:

Yes, static IPs would make it a lot easier, but the network plan (I cannot change) says private IPs for internal network (10.X) and for internal network (172.X) that is 1:1 NAT to public IPs based on MAC.

My current plan is to use a task that runs the command

```
route -p delete 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 10.0.1.1
```

every minute or so. And to higher the lease time for DHCP a lot. Do you have other suggestions?

EDIT 3:

When I only use the permanent route, my routing table looks like the following. But it is not working. I can not access the internet with this routing table:

```
IPv4-Route Table
===========================================================================
    Active Routes:
  Network Destination          Netmask          Gateway        Interface Metric
              0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       172.16.0.1      172.16.1.30      5
              0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.0.1.1        10.0.1.30      5
             10.0.0.0      255.255.0.0          On-link        10.0.1.30    261
            10.0.1.30  255.255.255.255          On-link         10.0.1.30    261
         10.0.255.255  255.255.255.255          On-link         10.0.1.30    261
            127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0          On-link         127.0.0.1    306
            127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255          On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255          On-link         127.0.0.1    306
           172.16.0.0      255.240.0.0          On-link       172.16.1.30    261
          172.16.1.30  255.255.255.255          On-link       172.16.1.30    261
       172.31.255.255  255.255.255.255          On-link       172.16.1.30    261
            224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0          On-link         127.0.0.1    306
            224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0          On-link       172.16.1.30    261
            224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0          On-link         10.0.1.30    261
      255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255          On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255          On-link       172.16.1.30    261
      255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255          On-link         10.0.1.30    261
    ===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Destination          Netmask          Gateway  Metric
              0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       172.16.0.1       1

===========================================================================
```

It only works when I use the following command:

```
route -p delete 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 10.0.1.1
```

Without this command it does not work, why?

Comment: Do you have a DG configured on both NIC's?

Comment: What do you mean by DG? We use a DHCP Server.

Comment: I mean Default Gateway.

Comment: yes, I have a default gateway on both NIC's. I delete it from the 10.X using the route command. That works fine. But when the NIC gets a new lease (for example by deactivating and activating the NIC) then the default gateway is again in the routing table and internet does not work. Just choosing other permanent metrics does not help. If you know how to solve this, I will accept YOUR answer.

Comment: How about configuring a static ip address on the server instead of using a DHCP assigned ip address? That's the customary way of configuring servers.

Comment: Yes, I would if I could, but it is not allowed in this environment. As far as I know it has something to do with software licensing based on MAC and IPs. I have changed my questions (EDIT 2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to add a persistent route to the routing table for the default gateway of the 172. interface with a lower metric than the route that was added for the 10. interface. Example:

```
C:\>route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
0x1 ........................... MS TCP Loopback interface
0x2 ...00 ff ff ff ff ff ...... Intel(R) 82567LM-3 Gigabit Network Connection
===========================================================================
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0        10.10.0.1       10.10.0.2       20
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       172.16.7.1     172.16.7.51       30
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1       1
Default Gateway:         10.10.0.1
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

I would type the command `route -p ADD 0.0.0.0 MASK 0.0.0.0 172.16.7.1 METRIC 1`

[Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727001.aspx#EEAA)

Re Edit 3:

You need to make the metric lower, not equal. When your routing table has 2 routes with the same metric, windows will load balance across these 2 routes. That means it will send 1 packet out the 172 interface and the next out the 10 interface. This is why you have to delete your other route. Go ahead and make the 172 route persistent with a metric of 1 and you should be all set.

Comment: Just adding a new route does not work. I can use the route command to delete the route to the default gateway to the 10.X interface. But Windows will create a new route when the dhcp lease gets refreshed.

Comment: I think you need to give more information about your DHCP config - why are your 10.X NICs getting config from  DHCP? Sounds like you don't want that config so why not use static config on those NICs?

Comment: It is not possible to use static IPs in this environment. The internal IPs of the servers can change very often.

Comment: Have you tried adding the route with the lower metric than the 10. route? If you add a persistent route with a metric of 1 windows will always prefer this route over the route installed by DHCP. A look at your routing table would help greatly.

Comment: I have edited my original post (see Edit3). But it does not work with just a permanent route with a lower metric.

Comment: I edited my post. You need to make the metric of the 172 route lower than the 10 route. When they're equal they will load balance which is not what you want. Make the 172 route a metric of 4 or lower.

Comment: Just adding the permanent route (route -p ADD 0.0.0.0 MASK 0.0.0.0 172.16.0.1 METRIC 1) does not help. Then the two 5 gateways are still there and so is my problem. The route print output is like the one I posted in edit3. When I change the route not permanent, then it works, but then I have to do it again for every new lease.

Comment: Oh I see. So it's not letting you add a metric 1 route while the other 5 route is already in the table? Have you tried deleting the `0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       172.16.0.1      172.16.1.30      5` out and then adding the persistent metric 1 route?

Comment: I don't know if this is what Daniel Gouveia de Souza suggested but have you tried going into the 172 interface properties, going to tcp/ip settings, clicking advanced and unchecking automatic metric and set it to 1? Then you may need to go into the 10. and do the same except set the metric higher.

Comment: No it's not the same Daniel suggested. I will test is on other servers (on this one it worked!) and come back to you later. Thank you very much so far.

Comment: Yes, changing the metric in advanced properties is the way to solve it. Thank you! I have tested it on other servers and it works perfekt.

Comment: I'm glad to help!

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to change the priority order of the NICs on the Advanced Configuration menu?

Under: Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections
Press "ALT"
Then under Advanced menu;Advanced Settings...

Comment: hmm, now it doesn't work again, one moment. I will try to figure out why it works and than not.

Comment: It works, but Internet is very slow. When I deactivate NIC 10.X it is fast.

Comment: There isn't anything left regarding the static routes that you created ? Have you tried resseting the routes how they were?

Comment: currently I have no routes, I have deleted all additional routes and deleted both nics and added them once again. So everything is in a "new" state. I can most sites, most of the times I will get a timeout. But to load a very simple site I need a minute. When I deactivate the 10.X NIC then Internet is with 100MBit (out internet connection). I think that now Windows does a kind of traffic shaping and tries to use both nic, but I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a persistent gateway to it:

```
route -p add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 <ip.of.172.intf's.gateway>
```

This is kept over reboots.